# Any idea of how to do the monthly dtr(daily time record) using php?

Tags: php, report, dtr

My problem is how can I fetch the record from database into specific day of dtr form. For example is when employee is absent in day 3 it skip day 3 and directly jump to another day when the employee is present. Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9JUN6TBRak

```
          <CAPTION><EM>
        <p class="civil_service_title">Civil Service Form No. 48</p>
        <p class="dtr">DAILY TIME RECORD </p>
        <p class="circles">-----o0o-----</p>
        <p class="line1">_____________________________________</p>
        <p class="name"> (Name)</p>
        <p class="civil_service_title2"> For the month of______________________________________<br>             
        Official hours for arrival <br>and departure 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;
        Regular days________________<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Saturdays___________________    </p>
    </EM></CAPTION>
    <form method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr><th rowspan="2">Day<th colspan="2">A.M.
        <th colspan="2">P.M.<th colspan="2">Undertime
        <TR><th>Arrival<th>Departure 
        <th>Arrival<th>Departure 
        <th>Hours<th>Minutes
            <?php
                $days = 31;
                for($i = 1;$i <= $days;$i++){
                    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);   
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></th>
                <td>
                    <?php 
                        echo $fetch['time_in_am'];
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
                <td>00:00</td>
            </tr>
            <?php  
                }  
            ?>
        <tr><th colspan="5">
        <div> Total </div> <td><td>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: "monthly dtr report"? I looked it up, still don't know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTR

Comment: please refer to the youtube link sir

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the link.

Comment: Now I do understand what you're working with, but I still don't understand your question. I think you need to share the bit of code that does this: "when employee is absent in day 3 it skip day 3 and directly jump to another day when the employee is present". Why? Normal database queries would return nothing when there's no data for the given day.

Comment: Hard to explain but what I want to do is exactly the same from what in the video is, that dtr monthly report. As what you can see in the video it skip day 6 & 7.

Comment: If you share your code, that which makes your DTR, then I can see what is going on. No explaining needed.

Comment: I put my codes there

Comment: Ok, that's very clear. Now the only other thing I need to know is: What is returned by `mysqli_fetch_array($sql);`. More precisely: Can you return the day?

Comment: it returns the record from my database but it postioned on day 1. I want it to positioned on day 11 since the date is Jan 11. Do you get it ?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Would you mind if I ask how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

Your main loop to get data from the data looks like this:

```
<?php
    $days = 31;
    for($i = 1;$i <= $days;$i++){
        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
?>
<tr>
    <th><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></th>
    <td>
        <?php
            echo $fetch['time_in_am'];
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>00:00</td>
    <td>00:00</td>
    <td>00:00</td>
    <td>00:00</td>
    <td>00:00</td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

That explains why your output skips days, and you run out of data towards the end of the list. When an employee is absent there's no data for that day.

Since you haven't answered my question, I have to make assumptions. I don't know what's in your database, the query on it, or what is returned by it. So I make it up. I assume you return the day-of-month and time-in for each day of the month you selected. The code above would then become:

```
<tr>
<?php
    $days = 31;
    $timesArray = array_fill(1,$days,['timeIn' => 'absent']);
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $timesArray[$fetch['day_of_month']]['timeIn'] = $fetch['time_in_am'];
    }
    foreach ($timesArray as $times)
    {
      echo '<td>'.$times['timeIn'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>00:00</td>';  // for other times
      echo '<td>00:00</td>';  // for other times
      echo '<td>00:00</td>';  // for other times
      echo '<td>00:00</td>';  // for other times
      echo '<td>00:00</td>';  // for other times
    }
?>
</tr>
```

This can be easily extended to contain other times, like time-out. I left out the table header, because I couldn't make sense of that.

The trick here is that I prepare the `$timesArray` for all the days of the month with the word 'absent'. This could be an empty string if you want to. After that I fill in the days where the employee is present, and finally I display the whole array.

Comment: I just want to clarifiy that there's no status absent from my database, its just when employee won't able to timein in certain day for example day 2 the employee won't login so there's no record in my database on that day so in dtr form day 2 is blank. Everyday that the employee won't able to do timein it skip that day in dtr form.

Comment: Yes, I completely understood that, and gave you an example of how to do that.

Comment: What's the use of absent there?

Comment: 'absent' is just a string, a placeholder. As I suggested, you can use an empty string. It is there so the array has an entry for each day.